# What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion, promotion, 7-essential-questions, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/write-and-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name wordpress.stackexchange.com (or whatever name will not run afoul Wordpress naming policies) . But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/write-and-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Suggest only available domain names (Check first) and one suggestion per answer!

> When considering domain names, keep
> these basic guidelines in mind:
>
> ```
> * The domain name should be available.
> * Prefer dot-com names over other top-level domains.
> * Prefer non-hyphenated names.
> ```

Please also take into account the information on WordPress' [about->domains page](http://wordpress.org/about/domains/), which states:

> For various reasons related to our WordPress trademark, we ask if you're going to start a site about WordPress or related to it that you not use "WordPress" in the domain name. Try using "wp" instead, or another variation. We're not lawyers, but very good ones tell us we have to do this to preserve our trademark. Also many users have told us they find it confusing.

### Update: Don't hold your breath for it

It appears **we will only get a distinct domain name if the site grows large enough**, not just when the beta ends. [The blog post has been updated](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), and more importantly, the WebApps site was launched as NothingToInstall.com, but then [reverted back to WebApps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com).

However, this means that our domain name will be `wordpress.stackexchange.com`, which [conflicts with the WordPress Foundation policy](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-will-the-wordpress-foundations-new-trademark-policy-affect-this-site) that the domain name cannot contain "WordPress". So should we look for a new `*.stackexchange.com` name that does not contain `wordpress`?

Comment: lets ask matt if we may use wordpress trademark as I believe that this will the main support forum for WP in weeks

Comment: I've seen negative reactions to WP Answers in the IRC channel. https://irclogs.wordpress.org/chanlog.php?channel=wordpress&day=2010-06-07#m648191

Comment: *@Jan Fabry*: The WordPress Foundation policy is related to second level domains, (i.e. `wordpress-answers.com` would be a no-no), *not* subdomains of other domains.

Answer (score 15):

**queryposts.com**

[Available](http://www.checkdomain.com/cgi-bin/checkdomain.pl?domain=queryposts.com).

Comment: this definitely works.  I liked wpoverlfow.com before, but this has much more life and wit to it.  I could take 'ownership of this name.

Comment: This is the best I've seen thus far because it is specific to WordPress just like "stackoverflow" is specific to programming and "serverfault" to IT. But the one thing I would prefer would be to get something that is about an error or faiure in WordPress to go with the same idea as "stackoverflow" and "serverfault" which I think makes their names brilliant and brandable. But I'm drawing a blank on what it should be. Help?

Comment: I'd also like something like this because when referring to the site when answering questions it's much clearer to write "When posting your questions or answers on *queryposts* be sure to..." instead of "When posting your questions or answers on WordPress Answers be sure to..." I've run into several cases where I've been answering and had to struggle to make context clear.

Comment: clear winner in my view. Snappy, relevant and available. Snap it up, before I do!! Mwahhahaha....

Comment: Great one! And for those who want error in name - no other WP function unleashed more bugs than improper use of `query_posts()`. :)

Comment: I missed this question the first time around, but I really like this name and domain.

Answer (score 8):

**wordpressoverflow.com**

or alternatively,
**wpoverflow.com**

Comment: Absolutely. This. I wanted to post this yesterday, but don't have the requisite 5 rep points to answer.

My preference, like kevtrout, is for wpoverflow.com

Comment: I read it as w-powerflow.com

Comment: not original might as well stay on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't see the appeal - stackoverflow makes sense for that site because it's a bit of an in-joke/inside reference, but 'overflow' won't have near the meaning here that it does there.  I think we should use something more specific to WordPress.  I do like the idea of using an 'inside' joke/reference as the name.

Comment: Please repost your suggestions as separate answers so people can vote, and remove this post. I can't reserve domain names with multiple answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

### answers.wordpress.org

The WordPress staff might be willing.

---

*Added by Jan Fabry:* I asked the SE team whether this would be possible, and this is their answer:

> I would have to think it through, but we would need to have control of *some* domain (even if it's just `wordpress.SE`) to administer the site, the OpenID accounts, and the network. That means that they would be, essentially, redirecting their sub domain from `answers.wordpress.org` to `wordpressoverflow.com`. I'm not sure if they would be interested in that but I don't see that we would be able to do it any other way. I would certainly be willing to talk to them about it, if they were interested
>
> Robert

*(I moved this to the main answer, since it is too important to be buried in a comment)*

Comment: worth asking it would give the site the biggest boost posible But where would level BB-Press??

Comment: If you can get the guys at WordPress to OK this it would be really great.

Comment: This would be my preference, but (as illustrated by the pages of ranting and raving on the WP-Hackers mailing list) I doubt we'll ever get the WordPress.org team to sign off on a non-WordPress project tied to the subdomain ... but I'd love to be proven wrong ...

Comment: I am seen as a troublesome user because of all that ranting and am blocked from the wordpress IRC for not using my IRC client right. I thought I had turned off the scripts when I hadn't. Therefore someone else should approach them about this after we have more votes.

Comment: Correction: I was the one that brought up the subject, I think. It wasn't me that was doing the ranting.

Comment: In other words, any domain name will redirect to a certain real (or master) domain? What would show up in the address bar?

Comment: @Arlen: As I read it `answers.wordpress.com` will redirect to the new address, which will be visible in the browser. Unless they talk about a proxy that forwards everything behind the scenes. Not that I understand why: isn't this just a DNS issue?

Comment: I don't see this as an ideal solution, because then this site would depend on that relationship continuing to exist, and the health of this community could be drastically impacted in a negative way were that relationship to dissolve.

Comment: You're right.....

Comment: I agree with @EAMann - Even though this site is doing wonderous things for WordPress users the fact it's not run by Automattic tells me they are unlikely to embrace it.

Comment: Pretty much any custom domain–enabled service uses CNAME records to point a (sub)domain at another server. I use it myself, pointing several subdomains of my website to ghs.google.com and my github webspace. So: `answers.wordpress.com. CNAME wordpress.stackexchange.com.`...

Answer (score 7):

**capitalpdangit.com**

Available

Comment: i *LOVE* it. ;-)

Comment: [For those that don't get it](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/08/lowercase-p-dangit)

Answer (score 5):

**expertwp.com**

Answer (score 1):

### wpoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Despite the suggestions, it's tempting to pull a name from the set of files included with WordPress. Several of them are taken, but not:

**wp-load.com**

Comment: Too bad wp-admin.com and wp-content.com are already taken!

Comment: I especially liked wp-config.com.

Answer (score 0):

### wpqueries.com

Available. **wpquery.com** is owned by someone in Nigeria, I don't know if it is for sale.

Answer (score -2):

**pressaddict.com**

Comment: Related names, like [wpaddict.com](http://wpaddict.com) and [wpaddicts.com](http://wpaddicts.com) are registered, but may be available for sale.

Comment: Not a fan of "addict" with its connotations. Plus, has the word "sad" in the middle!

Comment: I think the 'press' part sounds like 'addicted to the press, or media coverage, or journalism', The intention and sound and ut rolls off the tongue, but i think 'press' belongs to another entity entirely.

Comment: Not a fan of the addict part either :S

Answer (score -2):

### answers.wphelp.com

Answer (score -2):

wordpresshelp.com

Answer (score -3):

### wphelp.com

It is available.

Comment: [It is an existing site](http://wphelp.com/), but do you mean the owners are prepared to transfer it?

Answer (score -3):

pressthreads.com

or pressthread.com

Answer (score -7):

wp-exchange.com

Comment: Too similar to Experts Exchange, I think.

Comment: Yep I agree. wordpressexchange.com would be even worse ;)