# Ask Question link should be changed

Tags: discussion, design

I think that the Ask Question link would be more prominent if moved to the right. I tested it and like it much better that way. It is separated from the rest, and so it immediately stands out.

For anyone interested in looking at it, all I did is add `float:right;` to the askquestion class. Here is a screenshot of the result.

[image: Preview]

The `margin-left:228px;` of the mainnavs class could take a bit of tweaking also. Does anyone else have any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question with the reason why this should be changed.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if I would support moving the link arbitrarily to the right.

On some sites we do make the Ask Question link a different, brighter color to set it off and highlight it. That might make more sense.

Answer (score 8):

I agree that the *"Ask Question"* links should be made much more prominent. I agree with @Jeff Atwood moving it off to the side doesn't really make sense.

Maybe make it red with a shadow, or add a yellow halo or something.

-Mike

Comment: In print, the third color behind white and black is supposed to be red. My $.02

Answer (score 6):

I'd rather see more use of colours than a moving stuff around, the problem for me is not so much with placement, but about clear division and oomph, ie. standing out. Some buttons get alot of use, they get clicked numerous times every time a visitor is on the site, these buttons/links need to stand out above the rest(because a user wants to click them, and often, he/she needs to be able to locate them on the page quickly).

This is something i changed when i wrote my stylish skin, i like frequently used things to stand out, and to see some clear definition between listed items.

Here for ref:
[New Design Launched](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/new-design-launched/417#417)

I really hope my post in the design thread didn't offend, after all i'm not a designer, and i don't know how users view and expect websites to look/behave, but i did hope that in posting the screenshot it might help to illuminate some of the areas that i find make the site harder to use.

I'll be happy to post some more critique if it's invited, but going by the few responses to my post in that thread i'm a little hesitant to, though i still thank those that took the time to provide positive feedback on the post.

And for those of your finding WPSE a little harder to use, in whatever manner, i would advise you to install Stylish and get tweaking, you'll wonder how you ever did without it once you get cracking..

In short, i agree, certain links/buttons do need more prominence/oomph!.. :)

Comment: I completely agree with you. And from reading through the thread about the new design, i can't get rid of the feeling, that most of the top commenters over do agree too. Nothing against Jin & SE, but they just overroled the community over here and didn't even really react on any sort of critics. The new design, in hard, but honest words, was no proposal, but more a "eat or die" thing. Even if you're no designer, you understood what's important and i'd rather see your design tweaks than the current one.