# New Theme Design

Tags: discussion, design

Just curious... What's the background image in the header of the new design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a faint watermark of a rotary press machine. A bigger version was presented 
in the original [design thread](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-the-official-wordpress-se-site):