# What should tags be enclosed with?

Tags: discussion, design

Does there have to be anything at all around tags? For the record, tags are currently written like <permalinks> <rewrite-rules>. Can't we just drop them and not surround them with anything? We could put them in a box, or something like that.

Here are two examples from other sites:

[image: Two examples]

**Edit:** This is a voting post. Please vote for the idea you like best.

Comment: I feel the same way. However, the PTB don't seem to mind the visual ambiguity and so they're keeping it the way it is. The good news is that you can "fix" this using the *Stylish* FF plugin and just a little bit of overriding CSS. My email is in my profile if you would like a copy of what I'm using.

Comment: No they're not. It is just that no one really minds. Everyone just kinda feels the same way, and so they don't change it. Would you change it just because one person brought it up for discussion? If you did, it might get changed ten times before people agreed on one. Then too, if you changed it and than took a vote, more people might come voting on it.

Answer (score 5):

I vote for no extra characters at all. There are already three ways to make tags distinct: position, background and the hover effect.

[image: screenshot]
Screenshot with my user stylesheet.

Comment: +1 for nothing. Position and background is quite enough.

Comment: +1 for this or for square brackets. The angle brackets are odd and distracting and do not have an analog to WordPress tags. Further nothing in WordPress really references HTML as HTML is mostly hidden by WordPress so it doesn't make sense to use an HTML motif.

Answer (score 1):

[I had my doubts](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-the-official-wordpress-se-site/390#390), but I like the current version, with the reduced spacing. WordPress generates HTML, HTML uses `<>` to denote tags, and these are tags for questions. So I personally don't see a reason to change them.

Comment: WordPress can generate any output language, JSON for example. I'm not convinced. I switched the brackets off in my user stylesheet and like that much more.

Comment: @toscho: As have I. These are *concept tags*, not HTML tags. When I see angle brackets my mind says, "HTML!", not "concept!" Conflating the two ideas reduces clarity, it does not improve it. Fortunately, we are not defenseless in this cause.

Comment: Of course not, you have the power of the vote.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for them to be in boxes. They look pretty nice that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a design element.

In posts, put tags in brackets, like `[tag:plugins]` to produce

[plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins)

Comment: I did it that way for the record. Thanks for the tip, though, I never knew that before. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for square brackets, so they look sort of like shortcodes