# Anyone else think the links should stand out a little more?

Tags: discussion, design, hyperlinks

I am all for subtly in design, but the link colour is bordering on the unusable, in my opinion.

This is a screenshot of a paragraph with a visited and a non-visited link in it (Chrome on Mac OS X, preview area with [some changes](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/font-size-color-and-line-height-usability-issues-with-new-design)):

[image: Screenshot with visited and unvisited links]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font size, color and line height usability issues with new design.](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/523/font-size-color-and-line-height-usability-issues-with-new-design)

Comment: Was just discussed. They are supposed to be tweaked in _next deployment_ (whenever that is) and I really hope for underlines...

Comment: I'm not fussed by underlines, I think that they might have their own usability issues. A different colour with greater contrast should suffice, so long as they underline on hover.

Comment: @Rarst: I think Jin only changed the text color to #555. When I suggested to change the comments too he replied this would be in the next deployment, and the comments are currently changed. So I don't think Jin planned to change the link formatting. (You can see the "revision" of the SE software at the bottom of the page. Currently it's at 2011.4.1.4, so it was last updated today, later than Jin's comment.)

Comment: @Jan well, then links still suck... likely I will be joining "custom CSS the heck out of it" crowd soon. :)

Comment: @Rarst: I agree that the links don't stand out enough, I just wanted to remark that this question is thus not just a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: seems quick enough to fire off a quick css change. Of course, I have no idea what the implementation of an SE is like.

Comment: The body text was made a little lighter and the line-height was increased which helps the **[links](http://#)** stand out a little more.  Lately in my answers I've been bolding the links which really helps a lot.

Comment: When is this _next deployment_ coming? , it's hard to be a color blind and try to post or search for links, unless they are bolded I just can not see them

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for missing this post. I have brightened the link colors. The change will be in the next deployment. It should happen within the next 24 hours or sooner.

Comment: I think this change makes the links to questions in the activity dropdown box also blue, [standing out from the rest](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R2mmK.png). `#hlinks a { color: #877A56 }` is overwritten by `.question-hyperlink { color: #21759B!important }`.

Answer (score -3):

The links seem to stand out fine to my eye

[image]

... you can't see the link there?

Comment: I guess you’re sitting in the dark in front of a high quality non glare screen. Now imagine the opposite: an iPad. Compare your screenshot with [my modifications](http://i.imgur.com/w2Oa2.png). The brightness difference between the two colors is just **11.2%**. Way too low.

Comment: Yes, I can see a link at the edge of line and paragraph. But link in the middle of a large paragraph can be a very different story. How about adding screenshot of visited link? Those definitely need magnification. Anyway myself I just followed others on custom CSS road, underline on those links makes them work fine for me.

Comment: Also, the example is around 80% larger than actual size, not much of a defense.