# WP.SE.Com Built in Editor Bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today I tried a text with `bold+normal` face in a single word. When I separated them as
`bold + normal` — I can write them, like:
**got** me.

But if I join them like: "gotme" and try to bold the part "got" only, but "me" will remain normal, then I can't achieve that, see here below:
**got**me

It simply creates an italic one on "got". I think it's a bug of our editor.

#### What's the necessity?

Actually NO - there is NOTHING.
Camelcase thing can be a good alternative for such a joint writing, like: "GotMe". Today I tried to write "nanodesigns" with the first part (nano) in bold, and the second part (designs) in normal as it is - but I couldn't. If such a condition occurs then and only then we should need to have an eye on it. But for real Q & A, I thing it's not a widely necessity.

Comment: For information about why this is by design, see [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it's just easier to use HTML than deal with intricate combination of Markdown. Remember - the purpose of Markdown is quick and productive, not rich elaborate formatting.

```
<strong><em>nano</em>design</strong>
```

> ***nano*design**

Comment: <storng>nano</strong>designs - that what I meant it should be. And thanks to Rarst - at last I got it. I thought HTML won't work in this editor field. :)

Answer (score 5):

While @Rarst shows **how** you can write bold and italic, let me explain why it is **not a bug** that you cannot do that here with Markdown: **It is an aesthetic sin.**

Most fonts come in three variants: regular, bold and italic. The font stack on our site doesn’t even offer italic:

```
"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Tahoma
```

None of these fonts has an italic variant, because they are button fonts. **This is the real bug.**

So browsers create a faux italic (slanted) pseudo-font, which is bad enough for its own already:

[image]

Note the strange spacing and the broken font smoothing.

And now look what happens when you add bold to that disaster:

[image]

We get a pseudo-ligature **od** here.

If you want to emphasize a word, use bold **or** italic, not both. And avoid italic until this bug has been fixed. I have [reported this years ago](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/385/73) and nothing happened, so don’t hold your breath.