# Are we "WordPress Answers" or "The WordPress Stack Exchange"?

Tags: discussion, promotion

Do you refer to this site as "WordPress Answers" or "The WordPress Stack Exchange"? I know it says "WordPress Answers" in the header image, but we are one of the exceptions that got not just the subject in the temporary header image - probably because the proposed Area51 title was not too long and just fit.

Now that graduated sites will stay under "the Stack Exchange brand", and we don't need to search for a good domain name yet, does that also mean we should drop the "Answers" part? Now it may be confusing, as (I think) Google has no way of knowing that "WordPress Answers" refers to this site, while "WordPress Stack Exchange" does end up here.

It might also take the pressure off any trademark disputes: when you have an Apple Stack Exchange, a GIS Stack Exchange, ... I would not consider the "WordPress" part of the site name, it's just a subpart of the Stack Exchange network.

Personally I have no problem calling it "The WordPress Stack Exchange" / WPSE, but if we start promoting ourselves to outsiders, we should all use the same name.

Comment: I've been wondering exactly the same. Not sure yet if there is an obviously good answer. I would like to see a consistent shorthand, something like your proposed WPSE or similar.

Comment: Personally i don't think it matters a great deal how you refer to the site, as long as everybody understands each other, why care? I tend to refer to the site as the WordPress Stack Exchange, and that's primarily because that's what i see in the address bar(it would also be my preference if i had to choose).

Comment: I just returned to this because I continue to struggle with what to call it, especially for a shorthand. Nothing seems to me to be an obvious fit.

Answer (score 6):

I think **Wordpress Answers** is quite ok. I mean this site gives answers to wordpress questions, at least we try to do so :)

Well I'm running around to not answer the question. This Stackexchange is a great plattform (no idea what those guys think about themselves) -- really, a very nice made website and webapplication. I enjoy using it, even if parts are not working, it's fixed within 24 hours transparently. So I have no problem to admit that this site is running on it (everything else would be misleading somehow anyway), so for the moment, I thinks the subdomain is pretty well fitting if you ask me for a personal opinion. I have no problems at all to give credits. The WP core project might have but I have not.

In the end, I think we'll find the best domain name for it. Regardless of scammers, core-projects, misinterpreted trademarks (I thinks it's already the end of the list), *add your points here*. Oh well probably domain grabbers, if not covered by the first point.

So let's see. Even in case this runs into problems for the specific case, I'm pretty sure we can handle it altogether. And even it is lifetime under wp.se.com, I must admit, I don't see any problem with that. Okay well, maybe some day you want to have your own STLD first grade, but well, probably at the end of the beta.

Comment: Now another question is: Should this site be proposed as a cobranded site like Ask Ubuntu? I could see answers.wordpress.org (which currently redirects to wordpress.org) as a great place for this community.

Comment: @Voyagerfan5761: That would be very cool, but [Matt has said that they want to keep all support in-house on an open source stack](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227/lots-of-questions-lots-of-good-answers-but-not-as-many-active-users/232#232). So it's unlikely that this will happen.

Answer (score 3):

Casting a +1 vote to renaming it WordPress Stack Exchange / WPSE.

Comment: I agree I refer to it as http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and feel it fits withing the stack family.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are close to release I'd like to revisit this.

"WordPress Answers" was supposed to be temporary beta name when the [plan was for community to choose custom domain and name later](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be).

Now that latter is canceled can we still discuss our name, even if domain remains the same?

Personally I am against "WordPress Answers". All SE sites are about that. I think explicit "Answers" in name is:

- excessive;
- clunky to use in conversation/correspondence;
- poor for SEO and site image;
- overlaps with other sites and products: wp-answers.com, wpanswers.net etc.

Also do we have bulletproof confirmation that we can [use "WordPress" in name prominently in line with trademark stuff](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-the-official-wordpress-se-site/386#386)?

**Update**

As an idea - how about making WPSE (or variant like WP.SE) name of site? I mean make that shorthand actual main name.

- It solves any possible trademark issues ("WP" is not trademarked), while preserving WordPress branding with common abbreviation.
- SE stands for Stack Exchange, but also not uncommon for Special Edition and so is somewhat recognized as "advanced" suffix.

Comment: @Rarst: I agree that we should revisit this. Do you propose an alternative, or do you just want to "bump" the question? In that case you were of course free to edit the question instead.

Comment: @Jan Fabry I wanted to make clear as "answer" that I'd like to revisit it and personally not content with current name. I have no imaginative alternatives, in practice I mostly use "WordPress Stack Exchange" shortened to WPSE.

Comment: I would also like to add that the current site's title is "WordPress - Stack Exchange"

Comment: But it seems to me that "Stack Exchange" part is rather redundant in the header image. We're allowed to use "WordPress," no trademark issue there.

Comment: @Jin btw other consideration is that for `wordpress.stackexchange.com` domain calling site anything drastically different can be confusing. Such works for some sites, but not many go there. Anyway I think naming and design are to be handled as separate issues. I raised this in design thread because I was reminded of this thread, not because looking good is my only consideration for site's name. :)

Comment: @Rarst: If we would really call it "WPSE" or "WP.SE", people would probably expect a domain name like `wpse.com` or `wp.se`, both of which are already in use.

Comment: @Jan Fabry well, we are stuck with domain. And either "Answers" or written out "Stack Exchange" are excessive as part of name... I don't have better ideas. :( It is the issue with "WordPress" being both _product_ and _topic_. "Apple" SE just went with that little, "Android Enthusiast" went with user base suffix. I doubt we can go with just "WordPress" without getting lynched. Any ideas on suffixes we can use?..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brainstorm:

- WordPress Shop
- WordPress Garage
- WordPress House
- WordPress Publishers
- WordPress Repair

Or how about:

- Publishing House
- Print shop
- WPress Repair
- WordPress Programmers
- WordPress Programming

Or from our chatroom:

- StopPress (not sure why it's called that, but just an idea)

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for **AskNacin.com** ;)